# Number of lines and number of parameters in a function for angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube for my angularJS app.

I'm having issues because Sonar detects that my controller, which is a function, has a number of lines too important (more than 100) and a number of parameters (more than 7) too important also.

As controllers are functions in angularJS, it seems normal to me that these numbers can be easily exceeded.

Comment: I'd like to weigh in on the parameters part. For us currently the issue is that I don't know how to differentiate the rule for 'regular' functions (where the default 7 is already enough) and module definitions, where I may want to set a higher value, or completely ignore.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `controller as` syntax you can add your controller's functions onto it's prototype instead of having one massive function. e.g.

```
var MyController = function($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
}

MyController.$inject = ['$http'];
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.prototype.someFunc = function() {
    return this.$http.get('something');
}
```